# Select data based on condition that match multiple column values

Tags: mysql, select, search

I am quite new to the SQL world. Wondering if someone could shed some light on the situation below. I am trying to get a list of account numbers that contain both transaction codes 150 and 300 for that particular account.

Table:Transactions

```
+-------+--------+----------+
| AcNum | TxCode |   Date   |
+-------+--------+----------+
|   111 |    150 | 1/1/2019 |
|   111 |    100 | 1/1/2019 |
|   111 |    100 | 1/2/2019 |
|   123 |    100 | 1/1/2019 |
|   123 |    200 | 1/1/2019 |
|   123 |    300 | 1/1/2019 |
|   123 |    300 | 1/2/2019 |
|   222 |    150 | 1/1/2019 |
|   222 |    150 | 1/2/2019 |
|   333 |    300 | 1/2/2019 |
|   333 |    150 | 1/3/2019 |
|   444 |    100 | 1/1/2019 |
|   444 |    300 | 1/1/2019 |
|   444 |    150 | 1/1/2019 |
|   456 |    100 | 1/1/2019 |
|   456 |    200 | 1/1/2019 |
|   456 |    300 | 1/1/2019 |
|   456 |    150 | 1/2/2019 |
|   789 |    100 | 1/1/2019 |
|   789 |    100 | 1/2/2019 |
|   789 |    300 | 1/1/2019 |
+-------+--------+----------+
```

Here is the SQL query I created but it returns accounts that have 150 and 300 but it also contains the account that just have one of those transactions. I am looking for accounts that contain both transactions.

```
SELECT acnum
FROM   transactions
WHERE  txcode IN ( '150', '300' )
```

Desired result would be as follows

```
AcNum
333
444
456
```

Result I am getting is as follows

```
AcNum
111
123
222
333
444
444
456
789
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must GROUP BY acnum and count the distinct txcode to be 2:

```
SELECT acnum
FROM   transactions
WHERE  txcode IN ( '150', '300' )
GROUP BY acnum
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT txcode) = 2
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ddWfEcuQ96y7bQygFLUzuM/0).
Results:

```
| acnum |
| ----- |
| 333   |
| 444   |
| 456   |
```

Comment: I think he's allowing records with more than 150 and 300 (see 444), just not ones with only one of them

Comment: @Rogue check the demo.

Comment: Thanks for that! Running it with the count in the select helped me. I'm way off today

Answer (score 0):

You could also use subselects in the `IN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT acnum
FROM transactions
WHERE 
   acnum IN (SELECT acnum FROM transactions WHERE tx=150) AND
   acnum IN (SELECT acnum FROM transactions WHERE tx=300)
```

[See it in action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8f5d32/1/0).